# responsive image area map conflict with helix menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, helix

I am using a helix menu in joomla 3.3.6.
Ihave used the following script downloaded from http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html to make a image map responsive.

the problem is, after i added this script:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the dropdown function in the helix menu doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-rwdImageMaps needs jQuery, so if it is working without the script above ...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

... then you are probably already loading jquery and this one is causing problems.

Try entering ...

```
$.fn.jquery
```

... at the console level without the code above to see if it is already loaded.

**UPDATE**:

This sounds like there MIGHT be a conflict between jQuery and one of the two plugins we're talking about. Take a look at **[jQuery Conflicts](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)**

The other possibility is where the jQuery that does exist is loaded ... can you ensure your image map source file and code is executed AFTER jQuery is loaded.

Comment: i entered $.fn.jquery in the console and that was the response:

$.fn.jquery
"1.10.2"

Comment: If you did not have the script line above in the code, that means there is a version of jQuery already loaded and it is up to date ... the line can be left out.

Comment: yeah in the code there is allready a jquery loaded above, 
but if i left out the line the image map responsive function dont work anymore.

Comment: This sounds like there MIGHT be a conflict between jQuery and one of the two plugins we're talking about.  Take a look at http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: The other possibility is where the jQuery that does exist is loaded ... can you ensure your image map source file and code is executed AFTER jQuery is loaded.

Comment: ok thank you very much. but im not familiar with javascript :(
maybe u can help me out, when i post booth scripts?

Comment: Check the order they are loaded in ... jQuery FIRST.

Comment: yeah jquery is first.
1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js
3. <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
</script>
4. image map